# Enforce Not Null field in MariaDB using Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, peewee

Well, I'm trying to use `Peewee` for a small project. I need fields `text` and `url` (both `longtext` in MariaDB) to be `not null` and for `not null` I understand **not to allow a null value to be stored in the field**, so I did this:

```
database = MySQLDatabase("mydatabase", user="", password="123justkidding", host="localhost")

class MyTable(Model):
    text = TextField(null = False)
    url = TextField(null = False, max_length = 100)

    class Meta:
        database = database
```

and then, of course, I created the table and I started adding values, lots of values. The thing is that there are some `empty` values on `text` and `url` fields which I don't want them to be.
I ran this query:

```
SELECT `table`.`text`, `table`.`url` FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`text`="" AND `table`.`url`=""
```

and gave me four rows. So, What am I missing guys?

Also, I notice that MariaDB has [Text](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/text/), [Medium Text](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mediumtext/), [LongText](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/longtext/) as data-types
 and it appears to me that `TextField` in `Peewee` is default for `LongText` in `MariaDB`. Any way I can change that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `""` is an empty string, not `NULL`, so it doesn't violate the not null constraint.

Comment: @mata oh... well, got confused, somehow I thought that `""` was considered `NULL` in MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`""` is empty string. `NULL` is something different entirely.